# Run time Error with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to programming . I tried to implement a sample program but it gives me a run time error.but height property is a float type one.

> format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has
>   type ‘double’

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct user
{
    char name[30];
    float height;
    /*float weight;
    int age;
    char hand[9];
    char position[10];
    char expectation[10];*/
};

struct user get_user_data()
{
    struct user u;
    printf("\nEnter your name: ");
    scanf("%c", u.name);

    printf("\nEnter your height: ");
    scanf("%f", u.height);

    return u;

};
int height_ratings(struct user u)
{
  int heightrt = 0;

    if (u.height > 70)
    {
       heightrt =70/10;

    }
    return heightrt;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    struct  user user1 = get_user_data();

    int heighRate = height_ratings(user1);

    printf("your height is  ", heighRate);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scanf() calls have format mismatch problems:

1. `scanf("%c", u.name);` should be `scanf("%s", u.name);`

`%s` to scan a *string* whereas `%c` is used to scan a *char*.

and

2. `scanf("%f", u.height);` should be  `scanf("%f", &u.height);`

Notice the `&` added. You need to pass the address of the float variable.

Comment: Thank you  I fixed it using your instructions